# How we can make payment in Stripe Payment Gateway without Local/Web Server

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe V3.0. I am getting token successfully. I am using webserver and using api which hit the Stripe server and return successfully message. Code for get Token from Stripe server

```
 let card = paymentField.cardParams
    STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(card) { (token, error) in

        if let error = error{
            print(error)
        }
        else if  let token = token{
            print(token)
            //self.shippingButtonTapped()
            self.postStripeToken(token)
        }

    }
```

and in postStripeToken method I am hitting php Api and getting message of success/200 code and showing also a graph on Stripe dashboard. I followed this tutorial link https://www.appcoda.com/ios-stripe-payment-integration/

But I want to remove the complete part of my local/web server. So guide me please how can I make successfully payment without same.

This is the code for php server[image: php code]
  this code run on php server but I want that I can run this functionality from my side.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to process the charges on a remote server instead of local code running on php ?

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath I edited my post so please check

Answer (score 0):

This is relative easy. All you need to do is host the php code running locally into a remote server and then point the URL(in your code) to that server instead of localhost

```
let URL = "http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/donate/payment.php"
```

You can use AWS to spin up an ec2 instance and install xampp on it. Copy the php code running locally into the htdocs folder in the remote server.